# Error when passing facebook value: gson.JsonPrimitive can not be cast to gson.JsonObject

Tags: java, android, facebook, gson

I got this error when I parsed the **Facebook Json** from my Login.java to other activity:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be
>   cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

When trying to do this: (AnotherActivity.java)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        String token;
        token = getIntent().getExtras().getString("token");

        pref.getPref(PREF_IS_LOGIN);
        System.out.println("pref : " +pref.getPref(PREF_IS_LOGIN)); //res = 1
        System.out.println("token : " +token); //result = FB user token
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        jsonObject = gson.fromJson(token, JsonObject.class); //error at this
        String name = jsonObject.get("name").getAsString();
        Log.d("Root Activity", "Result:" + name);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using **facebook SDK 4.X.** for Android. It seems it doesn't want to be converted into **google Json**. Anyone know how to solve this case? Thank you.

Comment: Can you add stack trace?

Comment: post json data also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, just found out i don't need to use JSON or GSON to fetch data. 
FB Value can be passed using GraphApi instead and also adding this part: **protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { .. }** in other activity..

```
final GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                            try {
                                String name = jsonObject.get("name").toString();
                                Log.d("GraphRequest", "name:" + name);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```